# VB.Net Pausing and Resuming For-Next

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have the following code (VB.Net) that is doing exactly what I want (i.e Pausing at specific intervals/location of the code and Resuming when Messagebox button clicked)....... 
The only problem is that I used a messagebox; is there a way to use button instead to do the same job; No timer, No messagebox?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Index As Integer
    For KKK = 1 To 50
        Index = KKK / 5
        If Index = KKK / 5 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Paused at: " & KKK & " : Click OK to Resume")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for comments and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you upgrade to VS2013 Community (which is free), then you can use the Async/Await combination like this:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private MRE As New Threading.ManualResetEvent(False)

    Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Button1.Enabled = False
        Button2.Enabled = False

        For KKK = 1 To 50
            If KKK Mod 5 = 0 Then
                Label1.Text = KKK
                MRE.Reset()
                Button2.Enabled = True
                Await WaitForButton()
            End If
        Next

        Button1.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Function WaitForButton() As Task
        Return Task.Run(Sub()
                            MRE.WaitOne()
                        End Sub)
    End Function

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Button2.Enabled = False
        MRE.Set()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I must confess that your solution is very effective. Tested in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate.

Comment: Async/Await were first introduced with VS2012, so that would be the oldest version you could use.

Comment: Thanks Idle_Mind; I was trying for few days to do this update; I will figure it out... Thanks a lot for comments and answer; I used your answers to other members before and they are very useful... I recognize you... Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

2 buttons and a label is required. Try this:

```
Dim Pause As Boolean    

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim Index As Integer
    Pause = False
    Button2.Text = "Ok"
    Button2.Enabled = False
    For KKK = 1 To 50
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250) 'Just for testing purposes, do not use this instruction.
        Index = KKK / 5
        If Index = KKK / 5 Then
            Label1.Text = "Paused at: " & KKK & " : Click OK to Resume"
            Pause = True
            Button2.Enabled = True
            Button2.Focus()
            While Pause
                Application.DoEvents()
            End While
            Label1.Text = ""
            Button2.Enabled = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Pause = False
End Sub
```

Comment: This should work, but I think the CPU load might spike in the While loop.

Comment: Hi SkyMaster; I am trying the code, but it doesn't seem to do the job? I am still trying to make it work, but I got your idea; I agree with you on the CPU issue; do you have an idea how the Messagebox do this job without affecting the CPU??

Comment: The issue with the CPU is minimal. The DoEvents() method processes all messages in the message queue.

Comment: @Abbas1999 Fixed code. However this is better than a messagebox which is a modal window not allowed to do anything until you press ok. Tested on a first generation Corei3, CPU consumption is not critical.

Comment: One a single core system, the While loop will peg it to 100%.  On a dual core system it would be 50%.  The more cores you have the smaller impact it will appear to have.  If it's an issue, simply place a **small** call to Sleep() within the loop.  Sleep(10) is enough to reduce usage down significantly.

Answer (score -1):

You can do that by putting the loop into a separate thread, sleeping for the pause, and interrupting it with a button click. In this example, button1 starts the loop, and button2 interrupts it at `thread.sleep`.

```
Dim newThread As New Thread(AddressOf loopSub)
Delegate Sub textAddCallback(ByVal s As string)

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
newThread.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
newThread.Interrupt()
End Sub

Sub loopSub()
  Dim Index As Integer
  Dim textDelegate As New textAddCallback(AddressOf textAdd)

  Try
      For KKK As Integer = 1 To 50
          Index = KKK / 5
          If Index = KKK / 5 Then
              Thread.Sleep(36000) ' sleep the max amount of milliseconds
          End If
      Next
  Catch ex As ThreadInterruptedException
      Me.Invoke(textDelegate, "string to add")
  End Try

End Sub

Sub textAdd(ByVal s As String)
rtext1.text &= s
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi xpda; Thanks a lot... I am trying to test your code, but it does not allow me to AppendText in a RichTextBox inside Sub loopSub() because it is in a separate Thread.... 
... I was using RichTextBox  inside the For-Next Loop originally... is there a way to do that?

Comment: Yes, it's a little messy, but you can use a invoke a delegate. I'll add that (untested, but you'll get the idea) to the answer.

Comment: Thanks xpda for the effort, I am still having problems with the code; I wonder how messagebox do the job?